# Preventing nested builds using a Mutex

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion, xna, mutex

Background:

I'm using XNA and have a manifest processor, that will collate all assets in my content projects, categorising them by (among other things) their built type. To do this I need to build them. Some of these assets have a processor that itself uses the manifest, meaning that asset processor tries to invoke the manifest processor, so I get never-ending recursion.

Problem:

I've tried to use a named `Mutex` to detect when the project build is recursing and throw an error, which is handled elsewhere, but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
public class ManifestProcessor : ContentProcessor<ContentManifestAsset, ContentManifestContent>
{
    private static Mutex _LockingMutex = new Mutex(false, "ManifestProcessor");

    public override ContentManifestContent Process(ContentManifestAsset input, ContentProcessorContext context)
    {
        // If we've already locked on this object then we're doing a build as a result of building some other asset, so throw an exception
        if (!_LockingMutex.WaitOne(0))
        {
            throw new NestedManifestBuildException();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // Stuff that might cause this method to get
                // invoked again (via reflection)
            }
            finally
            {
                _LockingMutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
```

Am I using the Mutex class correctly? How can I detect `Process` being called recursively?

Comment: What kind of scenario is producing the endless recursion? If a reusable component is being built twice you could implement some kind of build cache and check against it. If there's some kind of circular reference then there would need to be detection for that.

Comment: Part of the process of building the manifest requires building all other assets. The process of building a particular asset requires building the manifest. i.e. they call each other. I realise that I've got a circular dependency meaning nothing would be able to be built, however I can work around that. I want to detect the recursion without resorting to catching an IOException when opening a file (which is how I first discovered it originally).

Comment: Caching should definitely help then. You should introduce a BuildStack into the pipeline to keep track of which assets are currently being built which will solve your recursion problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to implement a way to keep track of what is being built to detect the recursion. Caching will also improve the build performance since the Manifest can aggregate assets that have already been built. Look into using the [Mediator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) to decouple the Assets from the Manifests.

Sample:

```
public class ManifestProcessor : ContentProcessor<ContentManifestAsset, ContentManifestContent>
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, ContentManifestContent> BuildCache = new Dictionary<string, ContentManifestContent>();

    public override ContentManifestContent Process(ContentManifestAsset input, ContentProcessorContext context)
    {
        ContentManifestContent content;

        if(!BuildCache.TryGetValue(input.Name, out content))
        {
            VerifyStackIntegrity(context, input.Name);
            content = Build(input, context);
            BuildCache.Add(input.Name, content);
            context.BuildStack.Pop();
        }

        return content;
    }

    private static void VerifyStackIntegrity(ContentProcessorContext context, string buildStep)
    {
        if(context.BuildStack.Count(x => x == buildStep) > 1)
            throw new CircularBuildException();

        context.BuildStack.Push(buildStep);
    }

    private static ContentManifestContent Build(ContentManifestAsset input, ContentProcessorContext context)
    {
        // build steps for Manifest/Assets/Recursion
    }
}
```

If you want to prevent recursion period then the simplest way is to add a flag.

```
public class ManifestProcessor : ContentProcessor<ContentManifestAsset, ContentManifestContent>
{
    private static bool InProgress = false;

    public override ContentManifestContent Process(ContentManifestAsset input, ContentProcessorContext context)
    {
        if(InProgress) throw new InProgressBuildException();

        InProgress = true;

        return Build(input, context);
    }

    private static ContentManifestContent Build(ContentManifestAsset input, ContentProcessorContext context)
    {
        ContentManifestContent content;
        // build steps for Manifest/Assets/Recursion
        InProgress = false;

        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, but might be over-complicating things for my needs. Is there any reason why what I have wouldn't work?

Comment: A `Mutex` won't block a thread from recursion. It only blocks separate threads from entering the critical section at the same time.

Comment: An alternative would be to use a simple flag to indicate the method is already in progress if no recursion is allowed. I'll edit my post with an example.